# Need help on getting into a function in C++

Tags: c++

Here is the sample of my code:

```
//Function Declarations
void askChampSearch(string&, string&);

void displayChampDetail(string);

int main()
{
string searchedChamp;
string aboutUser;

cout << "**********YOU'RE GOING TO WANT TO MAKE YOUR PROMPT FULL SCREEN**********" << endl;
cout << "Welcome to my LEAGUE OF LEGENDS info guide!" << endl;
cout << "You can search any champion in League of Legends, and all" << endl;
cout << "of that champions information will be displayed.The information" << endl;
cout << "that will be displayed is: Abilites, Champion Lore, About The Campion, Best Build, and the Champions Wiki Page!" << endl;
cout << endl;

askChampSearch(aboutUser, searchedChamp);
displayChampDetail(searchedChamp);

return 0;
}

//Function Definitions
void askChampSearch(string& UserName, string& searchedChamp){
cout << "Thank you for trying out my program! I really appreciate it! What is your name? (Don't worry, your name isn't stored) ";
    cin >> UserName;
    cout << "Hi " << UserName << ", nice to meet you!" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "What League of Legends champion would you like to search? ";
    cin >> searchedChamp;
    cout << "The champion that you have searched for was " << searchedChamp << "!";
}

void displayChampDetail(string searchedChamp) {
if (searchedChamp == Ahri) {
    cout << "Ahri is a nine-tailed fox who is a whore" << endl;
    cout << "If Ahri hits you with a charm, you are fucked" << endl;
}


}
```

---

What I am having problems with is after my program leaves the first void:

```
void askChampSearch(string& UserName, string& searchedChamp){
cout << "Thank you for trying out my program! I really appreciate it! What is your name? (Don't worry, your name isn't stored) ";
    cin >> UserName;
    cout << "Hi " << UserName << ", nice to meet you!" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "What League of Legends champion would you like to search? ";
    cin >> searchedChamp;
    cout << "The champion that you have searched for was " << searchedChamp << "!";
}
```

---

It won't enter into the next one! For example. If the user types the Name Ahri it should display what I have done, but it says I need to define Ahri. How do I define Ahri within the second Void. Here is the code for my second Void:

```
void displayChampDetail(string searchedChamp) {
if (searchedChamp == Ahri) {
    cout << "Ahri is a nine-tailed fox" << endl;
    cout << "If Ahri hits you with a charm, you are dead" << endl;
}
}
```

---

What I am trying to do is, if the user types the name Ahri, it the information that I have provided.

The error code that I am getting is identifier "Ahri" is undefined.

Comment: Those two are not 'Voids', they are **functions**; see e.g. at  [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) or at [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson4.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searchedChamp == "Ahri"
```

It is a string. Other wise compiler tries to find a variable with name "Ahri"and it doesn't find it so it asks you to define it.

Comment: @TylerPerkins.: Exactly where you were doing the previous comparsion?

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you! It was really something that simple?! Oh my gosh!

Comment: @TylerPerkins.: select the answer if it helped.